# Android AsyncTask boolean changes to false after new page is loaded

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Im not entirely sure how to explain this but im new to AsyncTask and what im trying to do is send a UDP packet to my server and if i get a reply it sets it to online if not its offline. Right now it works correctly when the app is first opened but once a new page is loaded it says the server is offline even though its still online. Im not sure whats wrong with it. Am i executing the AsyncTask incorrectly or something to that extent? thats the only thing i can think of here.

CheckStatus.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;

public class CheckStatus {
//Check if the server is online

    public static boolean check() {

        try {
            byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("11.11.11.11");
            //create socket
            DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
            //set timeout
            clientSocket.setSoTimeout(1000);
            //send packet
            DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(Integer.toBinaryString(0x0006000000).getBytes(), 5, address, 44462);
                .send(p);
            //try to receive packet from server
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            clientSocket.close();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //if nothing is received set the the server status offline
            return false;
        }
    }   
}
```

CheckStatusTask.java

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;

class CheckStatusTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Boolean> { 

    private static boolean online;

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
        boolean flag = CheckStatus.check();
        return flag;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean flag) {
        online = flag;
    }

    public static boolean getOnline(){
        return online;
    }
}
```

main.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.swgproject.projectswg.ActionBar;

public class Main extends ActionBar {

//Include res/layout/main.xml
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    View background = findViewById(R.id.status);
    View status = findViewById(R.id.image);
    new CheckStatusTask().execute();
    if(CheckStatusTask.getOnline()){
        background.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.offline);
        status.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.offline);
    }
}


}
```

Any help is very appreciated thanks

Comment: Why do you have two `check()` function in two different places? And in your code you are not even using `CheckStatusTask`...well, and why is there a `main()` method? Android does not run `main()`

Comment: woops sorry i posted the wrong file for my main.java ill edit it. Edited it to have the correct file.

Comment: now I see the correct file:) but may I ask, why is `Main` extending `ActionBar` instead of, say, `Activity`?

Comment: @LawrenceChoy it seems to be an Activity part of a project, with a confusing name. Also OP, you're setting the layout to "offline" only if the boolean flag is `true`.

Comment: actionbar extends activity

Comment: @A--C It used to have a ! before it but i must have deleted it by accident when trying to get things to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your problem is that you are not accessing the result correctly. You asked the task to execute, and then access the result immediately without knowing the task finished or not. I would suggest to make your async task an inner class like this, so that it can access the variables of `Main`:

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends ActionBar {
    private View background;
    private View status;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            background = findViewById(R.id.status);
            status = findViewById(R.id.image);
            new CheckStatusTask().execute();
        }

        class CheckStatusTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Boolean> { 

            protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
                return CheckStatus.check();
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean flag) {
                if(flag){
                        background.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.offline);
                        status.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.offline);
                }
            }

        }

}
```

Comment: This worked without a problem thanks a ton! the only thing i had to change was add a ! in the if then before flag but thats because im my original code i never included it as A--C pointed out in the comments.